# Draw <svg> or <canvas> after headline [html, js]

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cool design and try to transfer it to a website.
What I want is basically shown on the picture below. I want a shape behind headlines.

[image: flyerdesign]

I've seen a canvas solution once on a template, but I don't know how they did it.
Obviously I can’t use simple background-image, because the headlines are different long/ height.
So my idea is to grab the SVG.js – library ( svgjs.dev ) or something similar and put a foreach js script.
Get headline dimensions and draw a canvas/ SVG. Position the canvas/ SVG via CSS as relative.
Do anyone got an idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve this design if you use:

- `inline-block` elements
- a `background-size` style set to `100%` (or `contains` if you don't want it to fit the whole width and height element)
- an SVG background image (prettier than bitmaps)

So You could set this style for such elements (`background-repeat` style seems to be removable):

```
header, h1, h2 /* whatever... */
{
  background-image:url("your_fantastic_resizable_background.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Thus, this design is kind of flawed: if two inline-block styled elements follow each in the code flow, the last will be appended next to the first, which is not you probably want. Hence, you'll have to insert between a line-break between:

```
<header>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>For a great logo</span>
</header>
<br/> <!-- sad. -->
<h1>Test 1</h1>
```

Below a working snippet made with a [GNU Head logo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Heckert_GNU_white.svg) ([Free Art License 1.3](http://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/)).

```css
header,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Heckert_GNU_white.svg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* seems to be not useful ... */
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
}

header {
  font-size: 4em;
}

header span::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>Test</span>
  <span>For a great logo</span>
</header>
<br/>
<h1>Test 1</h1>
<p>A first very good looking sentence.</p>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
<p>A second very good looking sentence.</p>
<h3>Test 3</h3>
<p>A third very good looking sentence.</p>
<h4>Test 4</h4>
<p>A fourth very good looking sentence.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Amessihel, but this is not what I needed.

A background-image with background-size of 100% for a variable height/ length headline-object would look in the end like....not well done.

But somehow you pointed me in the right direction. I mean, I am not super happy with this solution, because it's height-limited - but it's working for now.

I just used the :before and :after selector to split the image how I needed.

```
<style id="SCSS">
    h1, h2 {
        position: relative;
        background: #087f89;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
        color: whitesmoke;

        &:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 6px;
            background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/Amv4TJp.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: bottom 0 left 0;
        }

        &:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            height: calc(100% + 14px);
            width: 30px;
            background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/o9bsJN5.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: bottom 0 left 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
</style>

<article class="post-2 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-2">

    <header class="entry-header">

        <h1 class="entry-title">Headline</h1>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->


    <div class="entry-content">


        <p>This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up
            in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to
            potential site visitors. It might say something like this:</p>

        <p>…or something like this:</p>

        <p>As a new WordPress user, you should go to <a href="http://medical-laser.dev.cc/wp-admin/">your dashboard</a>
            to delete this page and create new pages for your content. Have fun!</p>
        <h2>Headline as well</h2>
        <p>This is an example page. It’s different from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up
            in your site navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces them to
            potential site visitors. It might say something like this:</p>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article>
```

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/smatplacid/pwaLuzdo/3

Comment: IMHO it depends of the nature of the background image. Since I did not have the wanted one, I could not see its rendering. Glad to see you found a solution.